# How do I properly point http(s) traffic to a squid proxy via bind9?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, proxy

I've set up a Ubuntu server running bind and squid. In my home network I've set up a raspi running pi-hole and dnsmasq. Dnsmasq is set up so that it overrides certain dns requests with the IP of the external Ubuntu server.
I want bind on this server to point all dns requests coming in to the squid proxy, so that this traffic goes through the proxy, without the need to set up the proxy on every device in my home network. Basically, like all these smartDNS services work.

I was not able to get this to work properly. The dns server works fine and returns the IP adress of my server:

```
~$ nslookup google.com 123.456.789.111
Server:         123.456.789.111
Address:        123.456.789.111#53
```

When I set up the proxy in my browser it works fine and Google reports `123.456.789.111` as my IP address. However, as soon as I implement the server's IP into my raspi's dnsmasq rules, it does not seem to work. No DNS requests resolve.

I suspect this issue roots in the fact that http(s) proxies use the connect method, which it cannot do with this setup?

How do I go around this issue? Is there any way to tackle this?
I tried a few different guides and also tried a one-click-install github script which uses sniproxy. Sniproxy works fine in this setup, except when it comes to https traffic, only http seems to work here.

Do I need to have a look into squid's peek and splice functionality for this?

I researched this a lot in the last weeks but haven't found anything that I could make use of. Any help is very much appreciated!

---

### Configs

---

My squid.conf is the standard one except an entry of `acl localnet` to allow traffic from my local IP.

My named.conf:

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

My named.conf.local:

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization

acl "trusted" {
    any;
};
include "/etc/bind/zones.override";
```

named.conf.options:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        forwarders {
            2001:4860:4860::8888;
            2001:4860:4860::8844;
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
        };

        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        allow-query { trusted; };
        allow-transfer { none; };

        allow-recursion { trusted; };
        recursion yes;
};
```

db.override:

```
$TTL  86400

@   IN  SOA ns1 root (
            2022100701  ; serial
            604800      ; refresh 1w
            86400       ; retry 1d
            2419200     ; expiry 4w
            86400       ; minimum TTL 1d
            )

    IN  NS  ns1

ns1 IN  A   127.0.0.1
@   IN  A   123.456.789.111
*   IN  A   123.456.789.111
```

zones.override:

```
zone "." { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.override"; };
```

Comment: I suspect that you are missing something. HTTPS was designed such that you cant proxy requests without implementing your own certificate/ca system.  Just using Squid + DNS cant get you there.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too but how do all these smartDNS services do that? SSL and https are working fine there…

Comment: With respect of https, DNS's only role is to provide an IP address.   SmartDNS is simply the idea of using a (recursive) DNS server in another country.  Some authorative DNS services will provide a different IP address in answer to a lookup depending in the IP address making the query - thus directing people to different servers which behave differently (ie block if the IP reached is X, allow if its Y).  SSL certs dont include IP addresses so all the servers can use the same SSL cert. There is no routing going through the DNS as happens with a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the help David. However I think this isn't the only way these smartDNS-services work nowadays. Many streaming services got behind that and do not use DNS as their only way to geo-block. That's why many smartdns-services, including the one I used before, deploy actual proxy servers behind the dns. All the self-deploy solutions on the web always use a combination of squid/haproxy/sniproxy and dnsmasq/bind for that.

Comment: David - quick follow-up: I tested one of these smartdns services available online - nslookup does not return the actual IP of hbomax.com, but an IP address from datacamp. A quick port scan on this shows that they have http/https ports open on that server. So I think this is their proxy server, to which their dns server points traffic to for hbomax.com

Comment: it could be a proxy server or a server performing differently.  The key bit is if it is  if they are using a proxy server it is a REVERSE proxy server, when you are using squid as a FORWARD proxy server to proxy everything.   In the case of a reverse proxy server they can deploy their cert on multiple machines and it will work for clients - but this won't work on a forward proxy server (unless the forward proxy supports, and you add and trust the forward proxy servers CA on each client)

Comment: With respect of smartDNS servers and HTTPS, they all have the same net effect.  Please trust that I know what I am talking about - I was running transparent proxying with squid 28 years ago when everything was HTTP, the ISP I owned and ran had a 1megabit UPLINK and everything was HTTP.  I have built and run a CA for an org to run client side authentication.  I've run authorative, recursive, hybrid and split nameservers for 30 years - so I  understand exactly how HTTP, HTTPS, DNS fit together. HTTPS is designed specifically to prevent what you are trying to do (effectively a MITM attack)

Comment: @davidgo Actually, what OP is trying to do (and what so-called smartDNS does) is not quite MITM. TLS (<= 1.2) does not prevent rerouting of the traffic as long as it ends up at the legitimate servers. No need to mess with certificates or TLS at all. Just look at the [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which is in the clear, and forward the TCP session along.

Comment: @Cachalot Your approach seems way too complicated. I think you only need dnsmasq to rewrite the appropriate DNS responses on your LAN and either squid or sniproxy listening on ports 80 and 443 on your server. Now, squid is usually deployed for real TLS interception (MITM), but I think it can also proxy the TCP session without tampering with TLS. I may be wrong, though. You'll have to check squid's documentation.

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira thanks for your comments! I’ll look into this, your approach seems a lot better than what I was trying to do!